# Proving $\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a$ from the integral definition of the natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Using the definition of the natural logarithm as $\displaystyle\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$, is there a way to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a$?

Proofs that I have generally seen have used the definition of the natural logarithm as the inverse of the exponential function $e^x$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\frac{d}{dx}e^{x\ln a}=e^{x\ln a}\ln a=a^x\ln a$$
using the chain rule and the fact that $f(x)=e^x$ satisfies $f'(x)=f(x)$. But is there a way to go about finding this derivative without using the definition of the natural logarithm as the inverse of the exponential function?

Comment: Then what is your definition of $a^x$ if you don't want to use the exponential function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to see something like this?

If we define $\exp: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ as the inverse of the $\log$ function, we get that, by the derivative of the inverse function and the FTC1:
$$\exp'(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\exp(x)}}=\exp(x)$$
And with the following definition of $a^x$ (for $a \neq 1$ and $a > 0$):
$$a^x:=\exp(\log(a)x)$$
and the chain rule we get the result you mentioned.

Comment: The comment above pointed out that $a^x$ is not particularly well-defined without knowing that the inverse of the exponential function is the natural logarithm. But since you derive that first this answer works perfectly well!